# Select across associative tables

Tags: c#, .net, linq, model-associations

Given the data model below I would like to select every ConfigurableItem that has a Schedule where IsActive =true.

[image]

I have looked at numerous examples re: associative tables and don't really get any of them due to the examples somehow magically ignoring the many-to-many association. There seems to be a lot of suggestion that I should be able to :

```
var f = from citem in context.ConfigurableItems
        where citem.ConfigurableItemSchedules.Schedule.IsActive == true
        select citem;
```

But that doesn't intellisense / compile. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

Im using a .dbml autogenerated from drag and drop from server explorer (sql server) so below is some code that is auto generated that may help answer some of the comments. They're just truncated snippets of the generated fields.

```
public partial class ConfigurableItem : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

        private long _ConfigurableItemIndexCode;

        private string _ItemRootPath;

        private string _ItemName;

        private string _HandlerAssembly;

        private string _HandlerType;

        private EntitySet<ConfigurableItemProperty> _ConfigurableItemProperties;

        private EntitySet<ConfigurableItemSchedule> _ConfigurableItemSchedules;
```

....

```
public partial class ConfigurableItemSchedule : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private long _ConfigurableItemIndexCode;

    private long _ScheduleIndexCode;

    private EntityRef<ConfigurableItem> _ConfigurableItem;

    private EntityRef<Schedule> _Schedule;
```

Comment: Isnt ConfigurableItemSchedules a collection?

Comment: You should use SelectMany because you have many rows

Comment: @Tomas Its an public EntitySet<ConfigurableItemSchedule> ConfigurableItemSchedules

Comment: what is the compilation error ? Because has seen, ConfigurationItem does not seem to have a navigation property called ConfigurableItemSchedules.

Comment: @Maryam - Not sure what you mean. After the select I was just going to   items.AddRange(f.ToList<IConfigurableItem>());

Comment: @tschmit007 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<Configuration.Linq.ConfigurableItemSchedule>' does not contain a definition for 'Schedule' and no extension method 'Schedule' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<Configuration.Linq.ConfigurableItemSchedule>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: That means that you context is "missconfigured". You should have a navigation property named Schedule in ConfigurableItemSchedule.

Comment: @tschmit007 Ive updated question with some extra code snippets. Are you saying there is a *special* property missing?

Comment: Well, I'm more familiar with Code First, but yes, imho, the navigation properties are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
var f = from citem in context.ConfigurableItems
        where citem.ConfigurableItemSchedules.Any(s=>s.Schedule.IsActive)
        select citem;
```

or something like that.

Comment: Unfortunately Schedule is not detected so I cant apply .Any(s=>s.IsActive). Error message is as per my reply to the tschmit007 on question comments.

Comment: I modified the answer a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: Yesss!! Nice one. That's great thanks. That's very good the pennies just dropped on a a couple more things re: your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reach Schedule but as ConfigurableItemSchedules itself has many rows (probably , I think) , compiler can not understand you need the schedules of which row.When you are using navigation properties in join you should be sure that the navigation property ends to just one row in destination Table or you should use `.SelectMany(t=>...)` or `.any()` to show compiler that you will select a collection of rows , may be it's better to start from the most bottom table like

```
var c = (from u in  context.Schedule
                     where u.IsActive == true
                     select u.ConfigurableItemSchedules.ConfigurableItems);
```